# How can I declare new struct in #Preview macro

Tags: swift, swiftui, macros, dynamictype

I'm converting XCP to #Preview macro and I was wondering if it's possible to make preview like this below.

```
#Preview {
    struct DemoView: View {
    // make view...
    }
    DemoView()
}
```

Is that possible? If so please let me know.
If not, please explain..

Comment: The closure must always return a View (for SwiftUI).

Answer (score 1):

`#Preview` macro conforms to the `PreviewRegistry` protocol, which has a static property `preview` to locate previews at runtime. It returns `DeveloperToolSupport.Preview`, and can contain a View or even a ViewController from UIKit in its body parameter.

Your example code will not execute because you're missing `return` for the `DeveloperToolSupport.Preview` body. Basically, function builder will not work here. (which bypass `return` keyword)

```swift
#Preview {
    struct DemoView: View {
    // make view...
    }
    return DemoView()
}

#Preview {
    let viewController = MyViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    return viewController
}
```